# Upcoming Date Function - Fixing Errors

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following code:

```
Public Function NextDate(date1 As Date, date2 As Date, date3 As Date) As Date

Dim ClosestDate As Date

If date1 >= Date Then
    ClosestDate = date1
ElseIf date2 >= Date Then
    ClosestDate = date2
ElseIf date3 >= Date Then
    ClosestDate = date3
End If

NextDate = Format(ClosestDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")

End Function
```

Where date1 <= date2 <= date3

Sometimes there are no dates being entered into the function and it returns #Error

Sometimes all the dates entered into the function are in the past and it returns 12:00:00am

What would I have to put in my code so that if there are no dates or all the dates are in the past then the function returns nothing (The cell looks blank)

*I'm using VBA in MS Access

Answer (score 0):

Since the arguments are declared as Date type, passing Null or empty string causes errors. And since function is declared as Date it must return a date.  Also, ClosestDate variable is declared as Date and therefore cannot be Null. Only Variant type can hold Null. Don't declare any as Date if you want to allow Null. Then modify last line:

`If Not IsNull(ClosesDateNextDate) Then NextDate = Format(ClosestDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Format() is probably not even necessary - could just set NextDate within the If Then Else block and eliminate ClosestDate Variable as well as the last line. Format() returns a string, not a true date, and Variant type defaults to empty string if no value provided. If result is needed in subsequent calculations, string result can cause issue. Either set NextDate to Null before the If block or use Else line. Following function returns either a true date or Null.

```
Public Function NextDate(date1, date2, date3)
If date1 >= Date Then
    NextDate = date1
ElseIf date2 >= Date Then
    NextDate = date2
ElseIf date3 >= Date Then
    NextDate = date3
Else
    NextDate = Null
End If
End Function
```

Comment: I would suggest to explicitly declare the parameters and return value as `Variant` to make it clear that it was not forgotten to specify a type and also mark them `ByValue`, because `ByRef` would be the default and is not necessary here: `Public Function NextDate(ByVal date1 As Variant, ByVal date2 As Variant, ByVal date3 As Variant) As Variant`